# Excluir registro a partir da janela Modal Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, modal, bootstrap

Estou tentando excluir um registro a partir da janela modal do Bootstrap, mas não está dando certo.

Vejam como eu fiz:

Ao clicar no botão de exclusão de algum determinado registro

```
<a class="btn btn-primary delete" href="#" data-href="#" data-target="#confirm-delete" data-toggle="modal"  id="<?php echo $codigoform;?>">Apagar experiência</a>
```

O jQuery interpreta o comando:

```
$('a.delete').click(function() {

    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var data = 'id=' + id ;
    var parent = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent();

    var $meu_alerta = $("#confirm-delete");

    $meu_alerta.modal().find(".btn-ok").on("click", function() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "deletar_formacao.php",
            data: data,
            cache: false,

            success: function() {
                parent.fadeOut('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
                window.location.reload();
            }
        });

    });
});
```

A página "deletar_formacao.php" lê o código por meio do método post e exclui o registro.

Detectei que é como se a janela modal e o evento onclick da classe delete estivessem competindo. Poderiam me dar uma ajuda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça da seguinte forma:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary delete" id="<?php echo $codigoform;?>">Apagar experiência</a>
```

Observe que retirei a chamada da modal através botão.

E pelo jquery, você o chama normalmente.

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
            var data = 'id=' + id ;
$('#confirm-delete').modal('show'); 

        $("#confirm-delete").modal().find(".btn-ok").on("click", function(){
...
```

Utilize esta lógica e veja se dá certo.

Comment: Agora deu certo, pessoal! Agradeço a todos!!!!

Answer (score 3):

```
$("a.delete").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var id = $this.attr("id");
    var data = 'id=' + id ;
    var $meu_alerta = $("#confirm-delete");
    $meu_alerta.modal().find(".btn-ok").on("click", function(){
        // $.ajax[...]
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rhmqxf7a/)

Comment: Com `var id = this.id;` poupas uma linha e usas menos jQuery.

Comment: Olá, Sergio e William. Por gentileza, vejam acima o meu código editado.  Onde que estou errando?

Comment: Quando executo o código,  a janela modal abre e fecha ao mesmo tempo.  verifiquei que se eu ocultar a linha ->  var $meu_alerta = $("#confirm-delete")      o modal aparece, porém, eu não consigo excluir.

Comment: achei que sozinho o _show_ era disparado pela função `modal`, então tenta com `$meu_alerta.modal('show')` para ver se firma

Comment: tambem sem sucesso  :/

Comment: coloca na frente do  `$('a.delete')` um `unbind('click')` ficando dessa forma `$('a.delete').unbind('click').click(` as vezes pode ser por qualquer incoerência no restante do código ou pela própria estrutura do HTML que faça com que o botão seja _"clicado"_ duas vezes e pode ocasionar esse "aparece" e "some", vai tentando, que uma hora dá certo

Comment: taambém nada :/